# wrong output for neural network written from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to write a complete neural network from scratch. However, the results are not very encouraging. My prediction output shows one for one single row only in the 3 class classifier. I will post my code and then I will talk about the problem in the output.

```
#labels or classes
#1=iris-setosa
#2=iris-versicolor
#0=iris-virginica

#features
#sepallength
#sepalwidth
#petallengthcm
#petalwidth


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')

df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

df.drop(['Id'],1,inplace=True)
#function to convert three labels into values 0,1,2
def handle_non_numericaldata(df):
    columns=df.columns.values
    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals={}
        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]
        if df[column].dtype!=np.int64 and df[column].dtype!=np.float:       
            column_contents=df[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements=set(column_contents)
            x=0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    text_digit_vals[unique]=x
                    x+=1
            df[column]=list(map(convert_to_int,df[column]))
    return(df)
handle_non_numericaldata(df)    

x=np.array(df.drop(['Species'],1).astype(float))
c=np.array(df['Species'])


n_values=(np.max(c)+1)
#to make the vector one hot encode
y=(np.eye(n_values)[c])
(np.shape((y)))
m1=np.size(c)


theta=np.ones(shape=(4,21))
theta2=np.ones(shape=(21,3))
#no of examples "m"

#learning rate alpha
alpha=0.05
#regularization parameter
lamda=0.05
for i in range(1,5000):
    z1=np.dot(x,theta)  
    sigma=1/(1+np.exp(-z1))

    #activation layer 2.
    a2=sigma
    z2=np.dot(a2,theta2)

    probs=np.exp(z2)

    softmax=probs/np.sum(probs,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    delta3=softmax






    delta3=delta3-y
    A2=np.transpose(a2)
    dw2 = (A2).dot(delta3)
    W2=np.transpose(theta2)

    delta2=delta3.dot(W2)*sigma*(1-sigma)
    X2=np.transpose(x)
    dw1=np.dot(X2,delta2)


    dw2=dw2-lamda*theta2
    dw1=dw1-lamda*theta

    theta =theta -alpha* dw1

    theta2= theta2-alpha * dw2





final1=x.dot(theta)
sigma=1/(1+np.exp(-final1))
z2=sigma.dot(theta2)
exp_scores=np.exp(z2)
probs=exp_scores/np.sum(exp_scores,axis=1,keepdims=True)
a=np.zeros_like(probs)
a[np.arange(len(a)),a.argmax(1)]=1
print(a)
```

The output according to me, as I have written this, all the output probabilities are same hence  it cannot classify properly.output should be 'a' array with 50 1's in the first row, 50 in the second, and 50 in the third. But all the ones are in first row. I have been meddling with this since last three days. Please help me figure out mistake I have made in writing this neural network.

Comment: I got an overflow on the line `probs=np.exp(z2)`. You can save time by using a debugger.

Comment: i have solved 'nan' issue.but still it is not classifying properly in the  end all three probabilities are same so it it can't classify between three classes.do you see any problem in the code overall???something that i am doing wrong?i have tried changing the hyperparamaets but it does not work.is my working method  correct the way i have used one hot vector and the way i have used the dimensions.for now i am not using biases ,i don't think they make this much difference @Emre

Comment: I don't know what you've changed so I can't say. I've asked the moderator to migrate it http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: i haven't change really.just tuned few paramenters.overall the code is same.does every step looks okay to you,if there is any huge mistake please let me know???